# Put in position N agents on a 2D plan

Tags: python, python-3.x

and sorry if my English isn't good (I'm a French student).

I am working for a school project, and I want to create a crowd movement in a modelised place with some walls, a fountain and street lights. I did almost everything : the AI is created and can move on the 2D plan, my place is modelised with some stuff like I said before, I used the Reynolds' Boid rules (Alignement, Cohesion, Separation) to approach the humans interactions during a crowd movement. I still have to program a function to modelise the physics when the people touch a wall or and other structure.

But I am working on the initialisation (creation) of the crowd and It doesn't work : the crowd is formed of N people (agents) where N is taken between 1 and 5518 (the maximum number of people due to the space restriction).
Here is the code :

```
self.agents = []
x = 50
y = 55
X = 0
while X < N:
    if x <= 100 and x >= 50 and y <= 165 and y >= 55:
        k = 0
        while k < 50 and X < N:
            for a in range(11):
                for b in range(13):
                    if (x, y) != ((70 + a),(104 + b)):
                        x += k
                        agent = UnAgent(x, y)
                        self.agents.append(agent)
                        X += 1
                        k += 1
        x = 50
        y += 1
```

I think there is an infinite loop but I can't resolve It. To better understand my code, here is an image of my plan on paint, then the second image is my program where all agents spawn on an unique plot (x,y) at the center on the place (that's what I don't want, I want every people are placed on an unique plot while traveling through the X coordinate then add 1 to Y coordinate then traveling through the X coordinate etc, and the people must not spawn in the red block so the fountain)

[image: First image of my plan on paint with explanation]

[image: Second image of my real program without the spawn feature]

EDIT :

Hi @PatrickArtner and thanks to pay attention on my question and to help me ! Your response is very useful, so I try to adapt your code (really understandable compared to my code !) and that's what I have :

```
def addMonumentCentral():
    '''Bloque la place de (70,104) à (80,116) avec des "briques" '''
    L=[]
    for a in range(70,81):
        for b in range(104,117):
            L.append((a,b)) # List of every unique tuple occupied by water
class Foule:
def __init__(self, count, largeur = 150, hauteur = 220):
    self.largeur = largeur
    self.hauteur = hauteur
    self.agents = []
    numAg = 0
    MonumentCentral = addMonumentCentral()
    for y in range(55,166):permise
        for x in range(55,101):
            if (x,y) not in MonumentCentral:
                agent = UnAgent(x, y)
                agent.largeur = largeur
                agent.hauteur = hauteur
                self.agents.append(agent)
                numAg += 1ajoutes
            if numAg == count:
                break
        if numAg == count:
            break
```

I am not comfortable with dictionary, so I adapted your first function to return a list of every block of water which return something like this : `[(.. , ..),(.. , ..), ... ,(.. , ..)]` where each couple of parentheses is the plot of water on the 2D plan.

Then, I apply your second function in my class Foule (which mean in English "crowd") and the only thing thar doesn't work (and that prevents the entire code to work, normally everything work perfectly except that) is the line `if (x,y) not in MonumentCentral:`. It seems I can't test a tuple with a list of tuples in Python : I'm a beginner on Python, It seems It doesn't work but I don't know how to do something like I've done previously with this line.

When I execute the code, I have this error line : `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`. Do you know how to replace the test line with a similar method of testing a tuple with a list of tuples ?

Yours truely,
Axel JOLY

EDIT 2 :

My code works now, here is the result :

```
class Foule:
def __init__(self, count, largeur = 150, hauteur = 220):
    self.largeur = largeur
    self.hauteur = hauteur
    self.agents = []
    numAg = 0 # Nombre d'agents ajoutes
    MonumentCentral = []
    for a in range(70,81):
        for b in range(104,117):
            MonumentCentral.append((a,b))
    for y in range(55,166): # On parcourt selon les y la zone de spawn permise
        for x in range(55,101): # On parcourt selon les x la zone de spawn permise
            if (x,y) not in MonumentCentral: # On check si c'est bloqué ou non
                agent = UnAgent(x, y) # Position de depart
                agent.largeur = largeur
                agent.hauteur = hauteur
                self.agents.append(agent)
                numAg += 1 # Iteration pour compter le nombre d'agents ajoutes
            if numAg == count: # On casse si on atteint le nombre d'agents voulu
                break
        if numAg == count: # On casse si on atteint le nombre d'agents voulu
            break
```

Sorry It is mostly in French, but It works perfectly now, with 1 agent to 5518 agents !

Comment: what are `x`, `y`, `k`, `X`, `N`, and these magic numbers `50`, `55`, `100`, `50`, `165`, `55`, `50`, `11`, `13`, `70`, `104`?

Comment: x and y are the variables (coordinates) of the plan. N is the number of people (number of agents). If X = N, every agent is placed on the plan. K travel through the X axis to place one agent evon every coordinate : 51 agent are placed beetween (50,55) and (100,55). If k = 50, the 51 people are placed and y += 1 to place 51 more agents on the X axis. When N agents are placed (X = N), no more agents are placed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a hard time understanding the while loops you used, so I rewrote them to simpler `for .. in range(..):` loops that go over the desired `x`/`y` ranges.

If an agent can be placed can be checked by using a `set` of coordinates that are *blocked* - I choose to use a `dict` - for the additional storage of what is blocking the tile (mostly for displaying purposes).

You block all tiles that are unuseable (place them in the set), before placing any agent. Then start placing agents, by checking if tile is blocked else place and count it. Iterate until all agents placed:

```
def addFountain(place):
   """Blocks the places (70,104) to (80,116) with water tiles"""
    for a in range(70,81):
        for b in range(104,117):
            place[(a,b)] = "~"  # water    


occupied = dict()               # dict as "playground" - it remembers which places are 
                                # already occupied. You can simply use a set of coords.

addFountain(occupied)           # add all water tiles to the dict (block the spaces)

maxNum = 74                     # place 74 agents
numAg = 0                       # placed 0 agents so far

for y in range(55,166):         # go over all tiles vertically
    for x in range(55,101):         # go over all tiles horizontally
        if (x,y) not in occupied:    # check if blocked, if not 
            occupied[(x,y)] = "A"                    # add UnAgent(x, y), I am adding "A"
            numAg += 1                               # count added agent
        if numAg == maxNum:                          # break if max reached
            break
    if numAg == maxNum:                       # break outer if max reached
        break

# visualizing the dictionary:
print("-" * (101-55+2))       # print plaza

for y in range(166,54,-1):     # print plaza (reversed so 55 is at bottom)
    print("|", end="")
    for x in range(55,101):
        print(occupied.get( (x,y), " "), end="") # print if in dict, else print space
    print("|")

print("-" * (101-55+2))
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------------------
|                                              |
|                                              |
      ... removed lots of empty lines ...
|                                              |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|               ~~~~~~~~~~~                    |
|                                              |
      ... removed lots of empty lines ...
|                                              |
|AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA                  |
|AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
------------------------------------------------
```

You can get a list of agents from the dict like so:

```
agents = [occupied[coord] for coord in occupied if occupied[coord] == "A"] (isinstance of your agent class)
```

You should probably adapt this code to your class structure.

Comment: If the map is mostly empty with only few obstacles, you can use sparse matrices to save memory and boost performance

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki  My dictionary is also mostly empty - it only has values for `A` and `~` where needed - the spaces are filled in if a key is _not_ in the dictionary - and this is only for demonstration purposes - the OP would only need a set that remembers whereever something was placed to check if a new agent can go there... you could spare some memory if you somehow length encoded the agents, but I guess they will be moving around so this point is moot here....

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner, my code is finally working thanks to your help !